paragraph goes down when float:left
why does the word "what" go down next line when floating left? why is not  besides the word why? they are both paragraphs. I am a html/css noobie am still learning, thank


.container{
    border: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container #what{
    float: left;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>I love carrots</h1>
        <p id="what">what</p>
        <p id="why">why</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



I was expecting to be beside the word why and not go next line

There are better options to use besides float. Do you need to use it?

The issue is that the <p> tags' margins interfere with each other. If you inspect the elements in your dev tools, you'll see that p#why still extends to the left edge of the page when p#what is floated, so they're sort of overlapping.
You can either

float p#why left too, or
remove the bottom margin of p#why and remove the top margin of p#what

Or you can of course go for a separate layout method like flexbox, but this is how to do it with floats.


.container {
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container + .container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* original */
.container #what {
  float: left;
}

/* option 1 */
.container #what2,
.container #why2 {
  float: left;
}

/* option 2 */
.container #what3 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container #why3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
<figure>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>I love carrots</h1>
    <p id="what">what</p>
    <p id="why">why</p>
  </div>
  <figcaption>original</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>I love carrots</h1>
    <p id="what2">what</p>
    <p id="why2">why</p>
  </div>
  <figcaption>option 1</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>I love carrots</h1>
    <p id="what3">what</p>
    <p id="why3">why</p>
  </div>
  <figcaption>option 2</figcaption>
</figure>



